# how to get accounts by label in google ads php api?

Tags: php, google-ads-api

I can get all accounts by the code below:

```
            $selector = new Selector();
            $selector->setFields(['CustomerId', 'Name']);
            $selector->setOrdering([new OrderBy('CustomerId')]);

            $mccAccounts = $managedCustomerService->get($selector);
            $entries     = $mccAccounts->getEntries();
```

But I want to filter the result to return only with those accounts that have specific label. How to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Predicates`. Like it:

```
 .....
 $selector->setOrdering([new OrderBy('CustomerId')]);
 $selector->setPredicates([
    new Predicate('HERE_REQUIRED_FIELD', PredicateOperator::EQUALS, 'HERE_SPECIFIC_VALUE')]);
 .......
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I used this predicate $selector->setPredicates([
          new Predicate('AccountLabels', PredicateOperator::CONTAINS_IGNORE_CASE, ['featured'])
      ]); 

but it gives me error InternalApiError.UNEXPECTED_INTERNAL_API_ERROR @ com.google.ads.api.services.common.error.InternalApiError.<init>(InternalApiErro]'